# Wordpress: Add a <link> tag to <head>

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, admin

I have a button in my plugin that creates a file based on user input. Now, I want to include that file in every page (frontend). I could simply inject a script, but the problem is that one website may recreate the file multiple times, which would result in having several instances of  in website head, which I'd like to avoid. Is there a way to programatically do this within wordpress backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's multiple way to include `<link>` into the head. But it depends on the type of link you want to include.

If it's a style or js file, you need to use `wp_enqueue_style()` or `wp_enqueue_script()` in a function and trigger it with [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action.

If the buttons and the file are about the template, you maybe need to use [`template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

Last is to use `wp_head` action, and echo directly the link. Play with the priority parameter to put it where you want. Note that the callback function could embed any logic to load the link you want.

Comment: None of the above. I want to include application type link.

Comment: I add the easier way to y answer